# Seemann's Dependency Injection, "Three Calls Pattern" vs Service Locator Anit-Pattern

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, ninject

I have created a WinForms MVC application using Dependency Injection (DI) and Ninject as the DI Container. The basic architecture is as follows

**Program.cs** (the main entry point of the WinForms application):

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ...

        CompositionRoot.Initialize(new DependencyModule());
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(CompositionRoot.Resolve<ApplicationShellView>());
    }
}
```

**DependencyModule.cs**

```
public class DependencyModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IApplicationShellView>().To<ApplicationShellView>();
        Bind<IDocumentController>().To<SpreadsheetController>();
        Bind<ISpreadsheetView>().To<SpreadsheetView>();
    }
}
```

**CompositionRoot.cs**

```
public class CompositionRoot
{
    private static IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public static void Initialize(INinjectModule module)
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel(module);
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return ninjectKernel.Get<T>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> ResolveAll<T>()
    {
        return ninjectKernel.GetAll<T>();
    }
}
```

**ApplicationShellView.cs** (the main form of the application)

```
public partial class ApplicationShellView : C1RibbonForm, IApplicationShellView
{
    private ApplicationShellController controller; 

    public ApplicationShellView()
    {
        this.controller = new ApplicationShellController(this);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void InitializeView()
    {
        dockPanel.Extender.FloatWindowFactory = new CustomFloatWindowFactory();
        dockPanel.Theme = vS2012LightTheme;
    }

    private void ribbonButtonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        controller.OpenNewSpreadsheet();
    }

    public DockPanel DockPanel
    {
        get { return dockPanel; }
    }
}
```

where

```
public interface IApplicationShellView
{
    void InitializeView();
    DockPanel DockPanel { get; }
}
```

**ApplicationShellController.cs**

```
public class ApplicationShellController
{
    private IApplicationShellView shellView;

    public ApplicationShellController(IApplicationShellView view)
    {
        this.shellView = view;
    }

    public void OpenNewSpreadsheet(DockState dockState = DockState.Document)
    {
        SpreadsheetController controller = (SpreadsheetController)GetDocumentController("new.xlsx");
        SpreadsheetView view = (SpreadsheetView)controller.New("new.xlsx");
        view.Show(shellView.DockPanel, dockState);
    }

    private IDocumentController GetDocumentController(string path)
    {
        return CompositionRoot.ResolveAll<IDocumentController>()
            .SingleOrDefault(provider => provider.Handles(path));
    }

    public IApplicationShellView ShellView { get { return shellView; } }
}
```

**SpreadsheetController.cs**

```
public class SpreadsheetController : IDocumentController 
{
    private ISpreadsheetView view;

    public SpreadsheetController(ISpreadsheetView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.view.SetController(this);
    }

    public bool Handles(string path)
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
        {
            if (FileTypes.Any(ft => ft.FileExtension.CompareNoCase(extension)))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void SetViewActive(bool isActive)
    {
        ((SpreadsheetView)view).ShowIcon = isActive;
    }

    public IDocumentView New(string fileName)
    {
        // Opens a new file correctly.
    }

    public IDocumentView Open(string path)
    {
        // Opens an Excel file correctly.
    }

    public IEnumerable<DocumentFileType> FileTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<DocumentFileType>()
            {
                new DocumentFileType("CSV",  ".csv" ),
                new DocumentFileType("Excel", ".xls"),
                new DocumentFileType("Excel10", ".xlsx")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

where the implemented interface is

```
public interface IDocumentController
{
    bool Handles(string path);

    void SetViewActive(bool isActive);

    IDocumentView New(string fileName);

    IDocumentView Open(string path);

    IEnumerable<DocumentFileType> FileTypes { get; }
}
```

Now the view ascociated with this controller is

```
public partial class SpreadsheetView : DockContent, ISpreadsheetView
{
    private IDocumentController controller;

    public SpreadsheetView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SpreadsheetView_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        controller.SetViewActive(true);
    }

    private void SpreadsheetView_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        controller.SetViewActive(false);
    }

    public void SetController(IDocumentController controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
        Log.Trace("SpreadsheetView.SetController(): Controller set successfully");
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return Text; }
        set { Text = value; }
    }

    public WorkbookView WorkbookView
    {
        get { return workbookView; }
        set { workbookView = value; }
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally the view interfaces are

```
public interface ISpreadsheetView : IDocumentView
{
    WorkbookView WorkbookView { get; set; } 
}
```

and

```
public interface IDocumentView
{
    void SetController(IDocumentController controller);

    string DisplayName { get; set; }

    bool StatusBarVisible { get; set; }
}
```

Now for my questions. In Seemann's book "Dependency Injection in .NET" he talks about the "Three Calls Pattern" and this is what I have attempted to implement in the above. The code works, the shell view displays and via the MVC pattern my controllers correctly open views etc. However, I am confused as the above definately has the flavour of the "Service Locator Anti-Pattern". In chapter 3 of Seemann's book he states

> The COMPOSITION ROOT pattern describes where you should use a DI CONTAINER. However,
>   it doesn’t state how to use it. The REGISTER RESOLVE RELEASE pattern addresses
>   this question [...] A DI CONTAINER should be used in three successive
>   phases called Register, Resolve, and Release.
>
> In its pure form, the REGISTER RESOLVE RELEASE pattern states that you should only
>   make a single method call in each phase. Krzysztof Kozimic calls this the Three Calls Pattern.
>
> Configuring a DI CONTAINER in a single method call requires more explanation. The
>   reason that registration of components should happen in a single method call is
>   because you should regard configuration of a DI CONTAINER as a single, atomic action.
>   Once configuration is completed, the container should be regarded as read-only.

This sounds like the dredded "Service locator", why is this not deemed service location?

---

In order to adjust my code to instead use Contstructor Injection, I changed my entry code to

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind(t => t.FromThisAssembly()
                      .SelectAllClasses()
                      .BindAllInterfaces());

    FileLogHandler fileLogHandler = new FileLogHandler(Utils.GetLogFilePath());
    Log.LogHandler = fileLogHandler;
    Log.Trace("Program.Main(): Logging initialized");

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(kernel.Get<ApplicationShellView>());
}
```

using `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions`, I then changed `ApplicationShellController` in order to correct my code to inject the `IDocumentController`s via ctor injection:

```
public class ApplicationShellController
{
    private IApplicationShellView shellView;
    private IEnumerable<IDocumentController> controllers; 

    public ApplicationShellController(IApplicationShellView shellView, IEnumerable<IDocumentController> controllers)
    {
        this.shellView = shellView;
        this.controllers = controllers;
        Log.Trace("ApplicationShellController.Ctor(): Shell initialized successfully"); 
    }
    ...
}
```

where

```
public class SpreadsheetController : IDocumentController 
{
    private ISpreadsheetView view;

    public SpreadsheetController(ISpreadsheetView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.view.SetController(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

but this leads to a circular dependency, how do I handle this?

*Question Summary:*

1. Why is my initial use of Ninject using "Thee Calls Pattern" and `CompositionRoot.Resolve<T>()` bad or different to the Service Locator Anti-Pattern?
2. How can I resolve the circular dependency issue above if I want to switch to pure ctor injection?

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 3):

At some point in the process, you have to use service location.  However, the difference between DI and SL is that in SL, you are resolving your services at the point they are requested, whereas in DI you resolve them in some kind of factory (such as a controller factory) and then construct your objects and pass the reference in.

You should create some kind of infrastructure that dispatches your commands and uses a factory of some kind to locate the dependencies used by the created objects.

In this way, the rest of your code doesn't have dependency resolution, and you are following a DI pattern except at the construction point.

Comment: Could you provide and example or a reference to an example of a "controller factory"? Thanks very much for your time...

Comment: @Killercam - I've not seen any WinForms code that successfully uses DI, but you can look at the asp.net MVC framework as an example (although many do not like the "conforming container" approach that MVC6 uses).

Comment: But why in Seemann book does he talk about Three Call Pattern as if it is to be used like a wrapper for the DI Containers "Resolve" method? This seems to make its use in most cases, service location... This is a single aspect of this chapter I do not appreciate... Thanks for your time.